# How to point subdomain to specific Laravel view? [Laravel]

Tags: laravel, dns, subdomain, laravel-5.7

I've a primary domain. 
Just for example let's take my domain as '**mydomain.com**'. And a subdomain of '**subdomain.mydomain.com**'.

My primary domain points to **/public/index.php** and the view rendered is 
in **/resources/views/welcome.blade.php**.

There is no problem with my primary domain. It is fine.

> Similarly, I want my subdomain to call the view located at
>   **/resources/views/subdomain/index.php**.

How can I do so?

> I'm using nginx web server, mysql 5.6 and php7.2

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thank You.

Comment: Since you're using laravel that would be using routing and changing the server configuration. You didn't even mention the king of setup you have so please update your question with that

Comment: Did you mean the view or the index.php ?

Comment: @AndreiLupuleasa whatever it is, but my subdomain should point to the sub directory/index.php or otherfile.php in /resources/views/

Comment: @Indra I updated the question. Is that enough? or you asking for something else?

Comment: Remove `subdomain` from folder path and it should work if you have the same setup.

Comment: @AndreiLupuleasa it didn't work.

Comment: Put `/resources/views/welcome.blade.php` not  `/resources/views/index.php`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188061/discussion-between-rajesh-k-chaudhary-and-andrei-lupuleasa).